# ExtJS Controller Reference to View won't work with different aliases?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Since yesterday I am trying to get why the reference to my view in my controller doesn't work.
I have two fiddles, the only difference is the name of the view and alias.

```
 4: alias: 'widget.mywin',
35: { ref: 'TestView', selector: 'mywin' } 
42: 'mywin': {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o4u3yvtb/6/ (working example)

```
 4: alias: 'widget.my.view.test',
35: { ref: 'TestView', selector: 'my.view.test' } 
42: 'my.view.test': {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o4u3yvtb/7/ (non-working example)

What I am doing wrong (with the naming)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be dots in alias names. It can be an array of short names or a string.

**Syntax**: `alias: 'widget.aliasname'` **or** `alias: ['widget.aliasname1','widget.aliasname2']`

```
alias: 'widget.my.view.test' //Wrong
```

Should be

```
alias: 'widget.myviewtest'
```

Comment: As separator you can use `-`, `alias: 'widget.my-view-test'`